# hive query that will fail if table is empty

Tags: hive, oozie

I have a series of workflows in oozie that will periodically fail silently by simply not filling the target table.  The failures are a result of, among other things, a change input like a non-ascii character or a double escape sneaking into the data, that kind of thing.  However, the job actually finishes successfully.  I would like the jobs to fail if the table does not fill.  Is there any easy way to do this directly in Oozie, or with a simple Hive query that will fail on an empty table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oozie doesn't fail the action as oozie sees that the hive query has been successfully executed , it doesn't care about anything else

A workaround for your case :

1. hive action that loads the table
2. another hive action that checks the count of the table , capture output.
3. use decision node such that if above captured output value is 0 then kill the workflow.

hope this workaround helps .